# Response with and in memory file with Django and nginx

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn, mime-type

I have a piece of code that works fine on my local setup (Django embeded dev server running on Windows) but not on server (ubuntu + gunicorn + nginx)

I build an Excel file et send it from memory like so

```
output = io.BytesIO()

workbook = Workbook(output, {"in_memory": True})

worksheet_user_list = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Fill file...

workbook.close()

output.seek(0)

response = HttpResponse(
    output.read(),
    content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
)
response[
    "Content-Disposition"
] = f"attachment; filename=test.xlsx"

output.close()

return response
```

Local setup response header :

> Content-Type:
> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Server response header :

> content-type:     text/html; charset=UTF-8

Any Idea why ?